# Drupal run update.php shown in Zip archive support missing

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-theming

Anyone suggestion to me. I have update drupal modules in live version, shown this error.

[image]

How to fix this...

Comment: For others out there, this helped me. Perhaps if you have cPanel you can look into software > Select PHP version (or something like this) and the select "zip" and also be sure to save :).

Answer (score 2):

you need to install the PHP ZIP extension

```
sudo yum install php-zip
sudo service httpd restart
```

unless you have **PHP7.0** in which case:

```
sudo yum install php70-zip
sudo service httpd restart
```